# Make changes in third party library

Tags: git

I have some library-dependency in my Java project that missing a feature I need. So I downloaded library sources, made that change and now I want keep my change and still be able to update version of this library. I imagine this like "repeatable change" or something like 'git pull' with rebase (if the library doesn't have any conflicting changes). But I don't want to make a git fork (because my change is too project-specific and I wan't to keep everything in a single repo). Probably git submodules is what I need, but not sure.

Comment: `git submodule` requires you to fork. Because you need a repo to pull/push.

Comment: A fork seems like the best choice for this problem, by far. If you own the fork, you can do the changes you need on it, and keep maintaining it. And forks/repos are cheap, I don't think you need to hesitate creating what you need for your project.